# How do Oauth tokens get passed back to the browser?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I vaguely understand what Oauth accomplishes, but I'm confused as to how the browser ends up acquiring the auth token when redirecting after a successful authentication. I see diagrams with 'client' and 'server' but I'm unsure what's meant by this, since in my mind the browser is a client to the webserver but that doesn't seem to be what's being described.

Is the browser just sending a fetch request every time they need authentication to a callback endpoint, or is the webserver generating its own token and then storing a seperate oauth token for talking to the authentication server?

Answer (score 0):

To summarize, 3 different options on how the authorization server returns the token to the original site/app/client:

1. In the fragment of the URL
2. In the body of a response
3. As a form value in a POST request

---

The user starts at your app (OAuth client) and you send them to the authz server to authenticate and authorize any access. Afterwards, they're redirected back to the redirect_uri, typically back to your app.

---

In some cases the token is included at this step. In the original spec, the authz server instructs the browser to redirect to the redirect uri and includes the token in the fragment portion of that URL.

A token is included in the fragment portion of the URL in the location header of a redirect. This happens in the implicit flow. This is not considered secure for a number of reasons.

[Example from RFC 6749 Sec. 4.2.2:](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2.2)

```
     HTTP/1.1 302 Found
     Location: 
     http://example.com/cb#access_token=2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA
           &state=xyz&token_type=example&expires_in=3600
```

---

In the other grant types it was included as part of the body of a *response* to a **/token** request. This step doesn't involve the user. This is just an API request and response. The web app makes an API call to the /token endpoint on the authz server, and the authz server responds to that API call with a 200 OK response and includes the token in the response body.

[Example from RFC 6749 Sec 5.1:](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.1)

```
     HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
 Cache-Control: no-store
 Pragma: no-cache

 {
   "access_token":"2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA",
   "token_type":"example",
   "expires_in":3600,
   "refresh_token":"tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA",
   "example_parameter":"example_value"
 }
```

---

There was an [additional spec](https://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-form-post-response-mode-1_0.html) that introduced a way for the authz server to send the token* as values in a "form" in a post request to the redirect uri.

*If a token was returned in the authorization response

[Example from OAuth 2.0 Form Post Response Mode:](https://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-form-post-response-mode-1_0.html#FormPostResponseExample)

```
     POST /callback HTTP/1.1
     Host: client.example.org
     Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

     id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiI...&state=DcP7csa3hMlvybERqcieLHrRzKBra
```

*This is a bit of a simplified view where user authentication is involved, but it covers the essentials.

Comment: So to clarify: the authentication webpage submits a post request to the original site you were on?

Comment: The authorization server is what serves up the authentication page. And the original site is the client. The user authenticates at the authorization server through the authentication webpage. To simplify: there are 3 different options. 1) When the user enters credentials an submits them to the authz server, the authz server responds with a 302 redirect with the location containing the redirect uri AND the token. This causes the browser to redirect to the redirect uri, which, usually, points back at the original site.

Comment: 2) User authenticates at the authz server. The authz server responds with a 302 redirect with the location containing the redirect BUT NOT a token. Instead, it's an authz code. If the redirect uri points at the original site, the original site receives the authz code, then makes a token request to the authz server. User is not involved in this token request step. In direct response to this token response, the authz server sends a 200 OK **response**and includes the token.

Comment: 3) User authenticates with the authz server. The authz server makes a **POST request** to the redirect uri by responding to the user authentication with a form containing the token and which automatically submits itself, thus triggering the POST request with the token to the redirect uri.

Comment: To summarize: 1) the authz server responds to user authn on the authentication webpage with a 302 redirect. The redirect location is the redirect uri AND the token in the **fragment portion of the URL**. 2) the original site makes a token request directly to the authz server. In response to that token request, the authz server responds with a 200 OK and includes the token in the **body of the response**. 3)  the authz server responds to user authn on the authentication webpage by sending an automatically self-submitting form triggering a **POST request** back to the redirect uri.